# JQuery - add value to the hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can add value to the hidden input filed? In this case input is being created as variable, and latter on inserted into the DOM if needed. The code:

```
<script>
    var forma = $('form#mali_oglas'),
    pomoc = $('div[role=pomoc]'),
    div = $('.mali_oglas_pomoc'),
    input = forma.find('input, textarea'),
    code = forma.find('#code')
    time_input = '<input type="hidden" name="time" />',
    paid_input = '<input type="hidden" name="paid" value="1" />';

    $('textarea').autosize();

    input.on('click', function(e){
        var name = $(':input:focus').attr("name");
        pomoc.fadeOut('slow').promise().done( function(){
         div.find("[data-pomoc='" + name + "']").fadeIn('slow');
     });
    });


    code.on('focusout', function(){
        var url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>global_info/gi_get_payment_code',
        kod = $(this).val();
if ($('input[name=paid]').length != 1)
    {
        $.post(url, {code : kod}, function(data){
            console.log(kod);
            $('.mali_oglas_img_paid').slideDown('slow');
            code.next('.mali_oglas_greska').remove();
            code.after(time_input.val(data) + paid_input)
            .css({'border' : '1px solid rgba(34,139,34,.5)'});
        });
    };
    });

    code.ajaxError(function() {
  $(this).next('.mali_oglas_greska').remove();
  $(this).after('<p class=mali_oglas_greska>Uneti kod je pogresan.</p>').css({'border' : '1px solid rgba(255,0,0,.5)'});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a jQuery method on a variable that is simply an html string

You can convert the variable to a jQuery object element wrapping it in `$()`

You can't concatenate the 2 inputs once one is an object so you would need to reverse the insertion

```
code.after( paid_input).after( $(time_input).val(data) )
/* should place "time_input" before "paid_input"
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the `val` method for a string, you should first create a jQuery object, change:

```
time_input.val(data)
```

to:

```
$(time_input).val(data)
```

Note that you cannot concatenate an object with a string, you should call the `after` method 2 times or use `add` method.

Answer (score 0):

`time_input` and `paid_input` are strings not jQuery objects, try this instead

```
time_input = $('<input type="hidden" name="time" />'),
paid_input = $('<input type="hidden" name="paid" value="1" />');
```